# Recuperar usuario de creación y ultima modificación

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo utilizando `TimeStampedModel` donde ya viene integrado el created y updated

```
class Universo(TimeStampedModel):
    nombre = models.CharField('Universo', max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Universo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Universos'
        ordering = ['nombre']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

En la vista del administrador indica el usuario que lo creo y modifico
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En template puedo llamar sus atributos con

```
{{u}} {{u.created}} {{u.modified}}
```

Pero no encuentro como traer al usuario que lo creo he hizo la modificación al template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalmente el modelo abstracto `TimeStamped` solo tiene los campos `created` y `modified` como tu mismo lo mencionas, estos claramente no guardan ninguna información relacionada con el usuario que realizó la acción. El historial que tu ves propiamente reflejado en el sitio admin no esta relacionado con el modelo abstracto `TimeStamped` o al menos no por defecto, en su lugar Django proporciona un modelo llamado `LogEntry`, ojo que este modelo solo guarda un registro de las acciones hechas mediante la interfaz admin pero esto no significa que tu no le puedas sacar provecho fuera de esta. Para ver los campos que soporta dicho modelo creo que no hay mejor manera que verlo por ti mismo en el [código fuente](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py).

Conforme a como puedes hacer uso de este modelo, existe una pequeña explicación en este [blog](https://ranvir.xyz/blog/django-admin-tips-and-tricks/#handling-history-model-logs-in-django-admin-panel) . Los lugares en donde puedes utilizar el modelo pueden ser muy variados dependiendo de que tantos detalles quieres guardar sobre las acciones y sobre que modelos quieres hacerlo. Un ejemplo sería que tienes un modelo de `Blogs` y quieres agregar una entrada al historial que muestre por alguna extraña razón las primeras 5 palabras del blog junto con los datos de quien la modifico,creo o eliminó. Para lograr esto hay dos soluciones:

1. **Utilizar el método especial save o delete del modelo.** Se suele preferir cuando no es una acción que se vaya a repetir sobre varios modelos, tiene la ventaja de que es fácil ver que son todas las acciones que desencadena una creación, modificación o eliminación de una instancia del modelo. La desventaja es que este método no es llamado cuando se hacen operaciones bulk data.
2. **Utilizar señales.** Permite agregar la misma señal a varios modelos pero oculta un poco las acciones que se desencadenan cuando se hace una operación sobre un modelo. He visto personas que recomiendan encarecidamente que se utilice solo en casos que realmente se ocupe por que hace algo complicado de mantener las aplicaciones pero esto ya es una situación personal.

Utilizando cualquiera de las dos opciones puedes lograr capturar el historial de las acciones de crear,eliminar y modificar sobre algunas instancias de cualquier modelo al agregar un registro al modelo `LogEntry`.

Algunas observaciones de la documentación.

> Overridden model methods are not called on bulk operations
>
> Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result
> of a cascading delete. To ensure customized delete logic gets
> executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.
>
> Unfortunately, there isn’t a workaround when creating or updating objects in bulk, since none of save(), pre_save, and post_save are
> called.

Finalmente una vez hecho lo anterior puedes recolectar información de cuando fue modificado/actualizado/eliminado un objeto a través de el modelo que ya te proporciona Django. Es posible que este modelo no se ajuste a tus necesidades por lo cual tal vez quieras crear tu propia implementación.